# Jasmine + Istanbul only

Tags: jasmine, istanbul

I want to get code coverage directly in browser, when running my Jasmine specrunner.html. All examples, that I have found with Jasmine+Istanbul also use Grunt/Gulp/Karma or some other cmd line tool. I don't want that.

Is there a way to get results displayed in  browser with Jasmine + Istanbul, or is a cmd test runner a must here?